# is there a way to make the browser reload my javascript code after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

how can i make the browser re-evaluate all my javascript after i make an ajax call. i am using mootools framework and i would like to reload the javascript added at the header portion of my html page

Comment: why do you need to do this?  Seems like you are going against one of the reasons to use ajax in the first place. Unless of course you are trying to do what @Robert Diana suggests, in which case, listen to him :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your ajax call is returning javascript as part of the response. I am not too familiar with mootools, but most of the popular frameworks allow you to eval javascript from a string. So, you can just grab the appropriate return value from the ajax call and "eval" it.

If that is not what you are trying to do, then I do not know what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new script tag using Javascript, the code within the newly loaded script is automatically evaluated. You cannot force the browser to re-evaluate the all the Javascript.

A possible solution to this is to place all your code in a function and then call that function when you get ajax response:

```
function myCode()  {
  // Your code here
}

myCode();
// Also call myCode when you get the Ajax reply
```

I am not familiar with motools so this is a general Javascript example. Also, on a side note, you generally shouldn't need to do this. Perhaps you should think about a better code design.